# How to reduce an array of objects in Python?

Tags: python

Apologies for the vague question, I am new to Python (JavaScript dev) and trying to reduce an array of objects into an array with objects combined if they have a matching ID. I tried using the `reduce` from `functools`, however, I am running into a wall.

```
    from functools import reduce

    # Attempt
    result = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), [
        {
            "id": '111',
            "error": "MissingError",
            "message": "Missing data",
            "type": "red",
        },
        {
            "id": '111',
            "error": "Warning",
            "message": "Missing attribute",
            "type": "red",
        },
        {
            "id": '222',
            "error": "MissingError",
            "message": "Missing data",
            "type": "yellow"
        }
    ])
    
    print('Result', result)

    # Expected
    expected = [
        {
            "id": '111',
            "type": "red"
            "messages": [
                {
                    "error": "MissingError",
                    "message": "Missing data",
                },
                {
                    "error": "Warning",
                    "message": "Missing attribute",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": '222',
            "type": "yellow"
            "messages": [
                {
                    "error": "MissingError",
                    "message": "Missing data",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

In JS I would use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: I'm confused by your edit. What's with the extra `error` key?

Comment: sorry, its to represent another attribute like `type`. I added a comment to @timgeb answer. I will amend the data

Comment: updated now, using `type`

Comment: just use a for-loop.

Comment: In any case, you already found out how to use `reduce`, the issue isn't that, it's what your reducer function is going to be. and `x + y` wouldn't work in JS either

Comment: How would I do this in 1 for loop?

Comment: So you want to combine them only when they have a matching `id` *and* `type`?

Comment: Only matching `id`, thanks, `type` does not have a pattern

Comment: Then what happens if you combine two different colors? Which one is stored at the top level of the combined dictionary? It seems to me like it would make more sense to store individual types with each message.

Comment: Sorry, only one `type` will be assigned to a unique `id`, its like a secondary `id`

Comment: Solved this by concatenating the `id` + `type` like `id*type` then splitting the string later on.

"id" = key.split('*')[0]
"type" = key.split('*')[1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a reducing operation, you're grouping by the ID and then accumulating into a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

grp = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    d = d.copy()
    grp[d.pop('id')].append(d)

result = [{'id': k, 'messages': v} for k, v in grp.items()]
```

Comment: It's a *kind* of reduction; `+` just doesn't operate on `dict` objects the way the OP is assuming it will.

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to add another attribute on the same level as `id`? that is coming from the `data`.

Example:

{
   'id': '111',
   'type': 'pie',
   'messages': []
}

Comment: @cafe123 then just add it to the dict. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, `result = [{'id': k, 'messages': v, 'type': ?} for k, v in grp.items()]`

Comment: @cafe123 if I understand correctly: `'type': v.pop('type')`?

Comment: Nope, `v` is a list

Comment: @cafe123 oh, right. Don't have an interpreter right now, might revisit this later. It's technically a different question, though.

Comment: @cafe123 what if for the same ID, say `'111'`, you have different types in different dictionaries, say `'red'` and `'green'`? The ID can be brought up a level because we explicitly group by it, so it's the same for all dictionaries under the `'messages'` key in `result` - but you didn't say that same ID implies same type, is this so?

Comment: `type` is like a secondary `id`, it is unique for each `id`

Comment: @timgeb I posted a slightly modified version of your answer as a community wiki. If you decide to edit yours, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2):

All credit to timgeb for their answer; this is just a slightly modified version to handle the edit to the question.

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for item in data:
    item = item.copy()
    grouped[item.pop('id'), item.pop('type')].append(item)

result = [{'id': id_, 'type': type_, 'messages': messages}
          for (id_, type_), messages in grouped.items()]
```

(`id_` and `type_` are named that way in order to avoid collisions with builtins.)

P.S. It is generally poor form to alter your question after one or more people have already satisfactorily answered its original version. However, since this is a pretty minor change, I figured I would post this.